# Array push takes forever in Node JS after response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape from yelp and have attached the code below. I have problem in storing the data into array.

Here is my code:

```
...
var id, title, link, neighborhood, address, phone = [];

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

while (scrapepage) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://www.yelp.co.uk/search?find_desc='+find+'&find_loc='+city+''+'&start='+page,
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    page += 10;
    rp(options)
        .then(function ($) {


            var json = { id: "", title : "", link : "", neighborhood : "", address : "", phone : ""};                

            $('.biz-name span').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this).text();
                console.log(data);
                //title.push(data);
                title_count++;
            });

           ...

            res.send('Check your console!')
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Crawling failed or Cheerio choked...
        });           
    }
});
```

So whenever I try to push the data to array, it just does not work, keeps waiting forever. If I remove the push, it consoles all the data.

I also tried with each instead of filter, but no luck. Also tried to put manually into array index, still did not work. May I know what am I doing wrong in the code?

**UPDATE**

I have added this at the top of the page.

```
var id, title, link, neighborhood, address, phone = [];
```

Comment: `title.push` - but you haven't assigned anything to `title` - shouldn't that code be failing with `cannot get property push from undefined`?

Comment: I have defined it as var title = [];

Comment: `I have added this at the top of the page.` but `title` is still not defined. Only `phone` is assigned to a new array, all the other variables are merely declared but otherwise not initialised..

Comment: Got you.. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to ask where is title initialized? I see the declaration but nothing that tells the system to initialize title as an array.

try

```
...
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

while (scrapepage) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://www.yelp.co.uk/search?find_desc='+find+'&find_loc='+city+''+'&start='+page,
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    page += 10;
    rp(options)
        .then(function ($) {

            var title = [], 
                release, rating;
            var json = { id: "", title : "", link : "", neighborhood : "", address : "", phone : ""};                

            $('.biz-name span').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this).text();
                console.log(data);
                title.push(data);
                title_count++;
            });

          ...

            res.send('Check your console!')
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Crawling failed or Cheerio choked...
        });           
    }
});
```

without the initialization the system has to go through a process of determining type and compatibility of parameters to be sure it can give you as close to what you've asked for. Sometimes Explicitly defining a variable can speed this process up.

also with this you shouldn't need to use title_count as title.length would have the count of elements.

Answer (score 0):

`push` will not work `until` assign `title` as an array type

```
then(function ($) {

            var title=[];
            var release, rating;
            var json = { id: "", title : "", link : "", neighborhood : "", address : "", phone : ""};                

            $('.biz-name span').filter(function(){
                var data = $(this).text();
                console.log(data);
                title.push(data);
                title_count++;
            });

           ...

            res.send('Check your console!')
        })
```

Comment: Hey yes, it works with title=[], my bad, but I have initialized it at the top of the page, just updated the code.

Comment: You still not assign title as array

Comment: Hey yes, got it., my bad. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.